# How to send the formated data to fire store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have few data like below:

```
Name (string), 
Age (string),
Number (string), 
ContactList (Array of string), 
messages (Array of string),
callHistory (Array of string)
```

All these above values i have collected from each screen and i saved it in `AsyncStorage`. I want to send these data as in same format as i mentioned in bracket. But how can i do formated and send to firestore ?.I am new bie. I tried all wasy but not able to understand about doing the formating and sending to fire store.

In my firestore my collection will look like is :

`Details` **(Collection Name)** -> `UserID(DocumentID) ->`Data[]` **(In this data i need to save as array. Like each time when i push data to this collection i need to save all in array (index format)).**

How can i do that ?.

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 1):

You would do this in 2 steps.

1) Get the data from AsyncStorage[1], store it in a variable in the format you want.

2) Set the variable in firestore.[2]

```
 db.collection("Details").doc("UserID").set(variable).then(function(){
 });
```

[1]https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage#getitem

[2]https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#data_types